# hover OR focus in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So I want to change the color of the text on `hover` **or** `focus`

```
<div class="hover:text-green-500 focus:text-green-500">foo bar</div>
```

But I was wondering if is possible to compress all in one statement, so I would not need to repeat the `text-green-500` for both. I tried the code below, but it becomes an **and** statement instead of **or**.

```
<div class="hover:focus:text-green-500">foo bar</div>
```

In pure css, what I'm looking for to do would be something like this:

```
div:hover, div:focus {
  color: green
}
```

Is that possible in TailwindCSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `@apply` to re-use existing tailwind styles so that you don't end-up writing `color: green` or whatever extra you would otherwise be writing in plain CSS>

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply

```
div:hover, div:focus {
  @apply text-green-500;
}
```

This way, you will also end up having less code in your `class` attribute.

Answer (score 14):

You may write a simple plugin to combine focus and hover into one  [custom variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) as described in the documentation.

The key is that `addVariant()` allows passing in multiple selectors as rules in the second parameter:

```
//tailwind.config.js

const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('hocus', ['&:hover', '&:focus'])
    })
  ],
}
```

usage:

```
<div class="hocus:text-green-500">foo bar</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/upd3HLYcNR) on tailwind play

Comment: Have you tried aria-selected? addVariant('holected', ['&:hover', '&:aria-selected']); this does not work.